# How to use regexreplace to compare two pieces of text in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I want to compare two pieces of code and replace bits that are the same with ellipses - basically, something like:

```
=Regexreplace(A1,JOIN("|",SPLIT(B1,",")),"...")
```

When I use this formula to compare "Help me, please, help me" with  Help me, houwitzer, help me", I get "..., houwitzer,..."

But when I use it compare two formulas (as text), say:

```
"=IFERROR(COUNTIF({" & JOIN( "," ,C8:C12) & "},""√ Yes"")/SUM(COUNTIF({" & JOIN( "," ,C8:C12) & "},""√ Yes""),COUNTIF({" & JOIN( "," ,C8:C12) & "},""x No""),COUNTIF({" & JOIN( "," ,C8:C12) & "},""≈ Don't Know"")),0)"
```

with:

```
="=IFERROR(COUNTIF({" & JOIN( "," ,C8:C12) & "},""√ Yes"")/SUM(COUNTIF({" & JOIN( "," ,C8:C12) & "},""√ Yes""),COUNTIF({" & JOIN( "," ,C8:C12) & "},""x No""),COUNTIF({" & JOIN( "," ,C8:C12) & "},""≈ Don't Know"")),0)"
```

I get a return that is just the second formula.

(PS: For my working environment I use this code with relational pointers instead of "A1" and "A2")

```
=Regexreplace(=INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN()-1,FALSE),JOIN("|",SPLIT(=INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN()-2,FALSE),",")),"...")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that [you can't use special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in Regular Expression:

> there are 12 characters with special meanings:
>
> - the backslash `\`,
> - the caret `^`,
> - the dollar sign `$`,
> - the period or dot `.`,
> - the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`,
> - the question mark `?`,
> - the asterisk or star `*`,
> - the plus sign `+`,
> - the opening parenthesis `(`,
> - the closing parenthesis `)`,
> - and the opening square bracket `[`,
> - the opening curly brace `{`
>
> If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex,
>   you need to escape them with a backslash.

In your case there are at least two of them: `(`, `)`

---

**Escape special characters**

To do this, use this formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"(\(|\))","\\$1")
```

You can add more characters in *regular_expression*:

- `(\(|\)|\*|\{|\})`

The final formula is:

```
=Regexreplace(A2,JOIN("|",SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B2,"(\(|\))","\\$1"),",")),"...")
```